# Homework help: Energy levels of two distinguishable electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, identical-particles

[image]

I suspect that the problem applies to spin 1-2 particles in general. But I am not sure how to find energy levels? How do you find the eigenvalues for Hamiltonians in matrix form?

(I am a freshman interested in physics and took advanced QM, but I think I bit off more than I can chew! Any help would be appreciated.)

Comment: Hi Freddie. Based on your question and your follow-up comment on sslucifer's answer, it seems to me that you are unfamiliar with tensor products / systems of multiple particles. You may be interested in videos [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc_1dsbkBEg).

Comment: Thanks for your help! The video was useful, I think I know how to approach the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question, I will not give full answer. However I can give you some hints, how to in general solve for eigenvalues and eigenstates:

a. The first part is the most basic question you will be asked i.e. to find the eigenvalues of a give Hamiltonian. Energy eigenvalues gives you basic but important information about the system. So to find the eigenvalues, look up **How to find eigenvalues of a matrix?**. You can find by solving *characteristics equation*. To find the eigenvalues specific to your problem , also look for Pauli matrices. Degeneracy is when two or more energy eigenvalues are same.

b. You can always add terms to hamiltonian, depending on the interaction with the system. In this case, interaction of spin with the magnetic field. This is also a very standard problem, an you can find modified hamiltonian for interaction with external field in the references.

These are some basic techniques you need to learn in order to solve advance problems. Have fun learning these.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. But I am still a bit confused, perhaps someone can clarify? Here's what I've got so far: a. do I just multiply the two 2x2 Pauli matrices in each term and add them together to get a final 2x2 matrix for the Hamiltonian? If so I know how to find the eigenvalues, but what does it mean for the particles to be distinguishable?   b. I think I need to add another matrix term for the magnetic effect in the Hamiltonian. But how?

Comment: If there are two distinguishable particles, they are in two different subspaces. So you need to direct product the operators. So if two subspaces have dimensions m and n, then the hamiltonian should have dimension m*n. You can add the interaction term like $B_z\sigma^{(1)}_z\sigma^{(2)}_z$